# Two .click functions on page, how to leave only one wokring?

Tags: jquery, ajax, prestashop

When using Prestashop's `HelpList` and creating two separate lists with both of them having AJAX enable elements - it loads two identical `$(".ajax_table_link").click` functions into the same page.

What that does is essentially makes you double click when clicking on it.

It loads up this code twice:

```
$(function () {
    $(".ajax_table_link").click(function () {
        var link = $(this);
        $.post($(this).attr('href'), function (data) {
            if (data.success == 1) {
                showSuccessMessage(data.text);
                if (link.hasClass('action-disabled')){
                    link.removeClass('action-disabled').addClass('action-enabled');
                } else {
                    link.removeClass('action-enabled').addClass('action-disabled');
                }
                link.children().each(function () {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('hidden')) {
                        $(this).removeClass('hidden');
                    } else {
                        $(this).addClass('hidden');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                showErrorMessage(data.text);
            }
        }, 'json');
        return false;
    });
});
```

I can modify the code itself - but i cannot make it load only one time.
How can i make it not double click?

Essentially i need it to cancel out itself if more than one of the same is loaded.

Comment: You could do something 'dirty' like if (!window.alreadyLoadedThisScript){ [function call]; window.alreadyLoadedThisScript = true}

Comment: Thats essentially what i was thinking about, since its backend anyways and wont have much use once done.

Comment: change the name of `.ajax_table_link` to something like `.ajax_table_link_main` and rename 1 function?

Comment: Post your Helper lists codes